# Create nested output as below from the given list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
product_list = [
{ 'id': 1,'product_name': 'Nokia 6.1','supplier': 'W3 Retail Inc','quantity': 1, 'product_cost': 10000 },
{ 'id': 1,'product_name': 'Samsung TV 32 inch', 'supplier': 'Sharp Retail Inc','quantity': 1, 'product_cost': 30000 },
{'id': 1, 'product_name': 'Nokia 1100', 'supplier': 'W3 Retail Inc', 'quantity': 4, 'product_cost': 8000 },
{ 'id': 1, 'product_name': 'Sony Headphones ','supplier': 'Sharp Retail Inc','quantity': 1,'product_cost': 750 }
]
```

output:

```
[{'W3 Retail Inc' : [{'product_name': 'Nokia 6.1', 'quantity': 1, 'product_cost': 10000},
{'product_name': 'Nokia 1100', 'quantity': 4, 'product_cost': 8000}],
'Sharp Retail Inc' : [{'product_name': 'Samsung TV 32 inch', 'quantity': 1, 'product_cost': 30000},
{'product_name': 'Sony Headphones ', 'quantity': 1, 'product_cost': 750}]
}],
```

I spent some time trying to convert above `product_list` to the output as above.
I tried this:

```
new_dict = {element['supplier'] : [element.items() for element in product_list if element.keys not in ('id','supplier',)] for element in product_list}
```

but this is not the output I want. Please help me solve it.

Comment: Is it necessary to write all the entire thing in one line? Code readability matters too you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```py
suppliers = {}   #Dict with the suppliers
for item in product_list:
    if not item["supplier"] in suppliers.keys():
        suppliers[item["supplier"]] = []   #Add new supplier to suppliers dict
        
    suppliers[item["supplier"]].append(item.copy()) #Add item to supplier
    suppliers[item["supplier"]][-1].pop("supplier", None)  #Remove unwanted fields
    suppliers[item["supplier"]][-1].pop("id", None)
```

This solution works but I suggest you use classes for the items and their suppliers instead of dicts.

Comment: I guess you mean item.copy() instead of i.copy()

Comment: Yes, correct. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas for this. Check below:

```
import pandas as pd

res={i:'' for i in set(df.supplier)}

for i in res:
    temp=pd.DataFrame(product_list)
    temp=temp[temp.supplier==i]
    temp=temp[['product_name', 'quantity', 'product_cost']]
    res[i]=temp.to_dict(orient='records')

>>> print(res)

{'Sharp Retail Inc': [{'product_name': 'Samsung TV 32 inch', 'quantity': 1, 'product_cost': 30000}, {'product_name': 'Sony Headphones ', 'quantity': 1, 'product_cost': 750}], 'W3 Retail Inc': [{'product_name': 'Nokia 6.1', 'quantity': 1, 'product_cost': 10000}, {'product_name': 'Nokia 1100', 'quantity': 4, 'product_cost': 8000}]}
```

Comment: Please stop posting identical "OP, can you please accept some answers" comments below your posts. They serve no purpose and they're just adding noise to the site.

Comment: Ok, i will do. I thought it was a common practice in the base of 'follow up' for questions that were properly answered but no answer was accepted 
(https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer)